# simple c++ operator overloading help

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, overloading, iostream

How do I overload the `<<` operator? From the error I am getting, it seems that `std::cout` doesn't know how to use `<<`.

This is in a class:

```
// uint64_t UPPER, LOWER;
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream){
    if (UPPER)
        stream << UPPER;
    stream << LOWER;
    return stream;
}
```

I am getting `error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << test'` which doesn't seem to make sense.

edit:

Neither this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, uint128_t const & val){
    if (val.upper())
        stream << val.upper();
    stream << val.lower();
    return stream;
}
```

nor this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, uint128_t val){
    if (val.upper())
        stream << val.upper();
    stream << val.lower();
    return stream;
}
```

is changing the error.

Comment: is `test` an `ostream` or a string?

Comment: I think you must add friend to your function..
see here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/Classlevelostreamoperatorandistreamoperator.htm

Comment: can you post the class in which this is defined and how you are using it?

Comment: im just trying to use `<<` like the `<<` for ints/strings/chars/etc. nothing special

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<` operator takes two arguments, a left hand side, and a right hand side. Therefore you have to define the function with two parameters:

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass &obj);
```

And you have to define it outside of your class definition, as far as I can remember. Inside of the class definition you can only have operators that take that class as the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

You typically want the `operator<<()` overload to be a 'free function' (outside of your class) so it can bind to the stream naturally:

```
// this is outside your class definition
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const myclass& rhs)
{
    // whatever...

    return os;
}
```

Then inside your class you declare it a `friend` if necessary so it can get to the class internals:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const myclass& rhs);
```

An alternative to having this be a `friend` (which some people consider to be breaking encapsulation) is to have a public function in your class that will output itself to a stream and call that in your `operator<<()` overload:

```
// inside class myclass - a normal public member function
std::ostream& dump( std::ostream& os)
{
    os << some_class_member; 

    // ...

    return os;
}


// now, the `operator<<()` overload doesn't need to be a friend
// this is still outside your class definition
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const myclass& rhs)
{
    return rhs.dump(os);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator<<` outside a class requires two arguments:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, type_you_want_output const& thing)
```